# Facebook not recognizing open graph tag og:title

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I keep getting the below error from Facebook -

```
Object at URL 'https://qa.recrouter.com/displayJob/Y6LtGNI0WH1rVndaKCwv4PUZkM925mcq' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.
```

However when I go to the debugger and see what the scraper sees, I see the below information is indeed contained in the page -

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="Pega Developer for Insurance Claims">
<meta property="og:description" content="
We are a leading provider of insurance products for commercial and institutional customers through one of the world&rsquo;s most far-reaching property casualty networks. We offer some of the industry&rsquo;s most extensive ranges of products and services, ...">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Recrouter">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://qa.recrouter.com/displayJob/Y6LtGNI0WH1rVndaKCwv4PUZkM925mcq">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://qa.recrouter.com/img/logo512h.png">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it - essentially, the error was due to a modification I had made to the  tag. To accomodate google sharing, I had modified the HTML tag to be as follows - 
`<!DOCTYPE html itemscope itemtype="schema.org/website">`

I changed this back to `<!DOCTYPE html>` and everything works

Comment: plz help me, i meet similar problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't get this error when I check your URL on the debugger, the og:title tag seems to work perfectly. Try to have a look again ;)

Comment: I fixed it - essentially, the error was due to a modification I had made to the <html> tag. To accomodate google sharing, I had modified the HTML tag to be as follows - <!DOCTYPE html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/website"> - I changed this back to <!DOCTYPE html> and everything works